# Using Gmail address with Bootstrap contact form - it's not working :(

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, email, contact-form

I'm using a Bootstrap theme called "Clean Blog" (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/).

In the contact.html file, there is a note in the HTML that says: 
"WARNING: Some web hosts do not allow emails to be sent through forms to common mail hosts like Gmail or Yahoo. It's recommended that you use a private domain email address!"

I only have a gmail address. I made a new address with protonmail, thinking I could just forward the mail to my gmail account, but the e-mail still isn't working.

Is there a workaround??

Comment: Is the mail sent? If not, what's the error code? are you using the php mail() function or phpmailer?

Comment: Bootstrap is a frontend templating framework, it doesn't support sending emails at all. If you have any, can you share your server-side code? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: The comment is referring to `./mail/contact_me.php` as its very basic and its using the mail() function. If you want to send from your gmail account then you cant you would need to use SMTP, but it should work if the host has set up an MTA for PHP just change `$to = 'yourname@gmail.com';`, but will most likely land in your spam folder, if you want to use gmail and SMTP you should switch out that code with PHPMailer and also add csrf to the form else your get ALOT of spam to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found an API called formspree.io and had to add a few class tags to the form.

It works such that the site sends the message through formspree then it bounces to my gmail account.